# How Can I Calculate a Numerical Difference between 2 Durations in Java (Using mpxj Library)?

Tags: java, mpxj

For example, I want to calculate the duration difference between 2 activities. Activity 1 has a 13 day duration. Activity 2 has a 5 day duration. I know Microsoft Project has difficulties doing operations with Durations. Thanks in advance!

Needed answer: 13-5 = 8
Ideal answer: 8 days

Comment: Unclear what your question is. Are you asking how to subtract one number from another? It might help if you posted some code.

Comment: It's subtracting 1 duration from another. You can't do a direct computation with duration variables.

Comment: Which class is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Durations both have the same time units, you can perform a simple subtraction:

```
Duration d1 = Duration.getInstance(13, TimeUnit.DAYS);
Duration d2 = Duration.getInstance(5, TimeUnit.DAYS);
Duration result = Duration.getInstance(d1.getDuration() - d2.getDuration(), TimeUnit.DAYS);
```

If you have different time units, you need to perform a conversion first:

```
Duration d1 = Duration.getInstance(13, TimeUnit.DAYS);
Duration d2 = Duration.getInstance(40, TimeUnit.HOURS);
Duration d3 = d2.convertUnits(TimeUnit.DAYS, project.getProjectProperties());
Duration result = Duration.getInstance(d1.getDuration() - d3.getDuration(), TimeUnit.DAYS);
```

In the example above, the second duration is in hours (assuming 8 hours per working day), which we convert to days prior to calculating the difference. Note that we pass in the project properties to the `convertUnits` method. This provides the details of how many hours there are in a working day and so on to allow an accurate conversion. There are other variants of the `convertUnits` method which allow you to pass in these values yourself.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I convert an existing duration in an activity to a float value, I'm trying to do this comparison a few thousand times.

Comment: `Duration.getDuration()` returns the numeric part of the duration as a `double`. e.g. from the example above, `d1.getDuration()`.